# How to add words（comment） on 3D model in Scenekit ？

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, scenekit

I showed a 3D model in my app with Scenekit. The model could rotate, scale, move by gesture. Now I need to add some comments on screen to explain every part of the model is what(such as a cardiac module, includes cardiac muscle, blood vessel...). The comments should always follow the part of model, when the model transform, **and word's size will not change, always face to User**. But I do not know how to achieved that.

My idea is to make **3D world coordinate to screen coordinate**, and add UILabels on SCNView, when model transforms, change UILabels frame. But I don't know how to make coordinate convert. 
Of course, it could be **a better way**, I don't know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is taken from an `ARKit` project, but with respect to having a text label attached to an `SCNNode` and always facing the user, this is what you need -

```swift
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        guard let featureAnchor = anchor as? FeatureAnchor else {
            return nil
        }
        let feature = featureAnchor.feature

        let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
        billboardConstraint.freeAxes = SCNBillboardAxis.Y

        let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: Global.dotRadius)
        sphere.firstMaterial?.transparency = Global.annotationTransparency
        sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
        sphere.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
        node.constraints = [billboardConstraint]

        let text = SCNText(string: feature.description, extrusionDepth: Global.textDepth)
        text.chamferRadius = Global.textDepth
        text.firstMaterial?.transparency = Global.annotationTransparency
        text.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
        text.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
        text.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        text.font = Global.textFont
        text.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter

        let (min, max) = text.boundingBox
        let dx: Float = (max.x - min.x) / 2.0 // x = center
        let dy: Float = min.y // y = bottom
        let dz: Float = Float(Global.textDepth) / 2.0 // z = center

        let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)
        textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(dx, dy, dz)
        textNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(Global.textScale, Global.textScale, Global.textScale)

        node.addChildNode(textNode)

        return node
    }
```

Comment: thx, i do this and it worked. but textNodes looks small in the distance
and big on the contrary.  How to make them aways look the same size?

Comment: I haven't tried this one, but probably you can adjust scale via `SCNTransformConstraint` depending on the distance.